# how I could redirect variable that contain a value and the value contain another value in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, variables, redirect

I have a  variable varpage this is equal to start and I need to obtain start value as output and save to file

this is my code

```
  varpage="start"
    start="1,4,1,0,1,1,1,30,12,;1,4,1,2,1,1,1,30,29,;1,5,1,2,0,1,1,30,29,;1,4,1,2,0,1,1,30,29,;1,4,1,0,1,1,1,30,29,;"

      File.open("mmmm3", "w") do |f|  f.puts  "@#{varpage}"  end
```

I expected this output

**"1,4,1,0,1,1,1,30,12,;1,4,1,2,1,1,1,30,29,;1,5,1,2,0,1,1,30,29,;1,4,1,2,0,1,1,30,29,;1,4,1,0,1,1,1,30,29,;"**

Please help me

Comment: By "output" do you mean the contents of the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use a hash:

```
varpage = "start"
options = {"start" => "1,4,1,0,1,1,1,30,12,;1,4,1,2,1,1,1,30,29,;1,5,1,2,0,1,1,30,29,;1,4,1,2,0,1,1,30,29,;1,4,1,0,1,1,1,30,29,;"}

File.open("mmmm3", "w" do |f|
  f.puts options[varpage]
end
```